# Start a new ID every time the date changes in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like the following

```
[
 { id: 332, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 0 },
 { id: 342, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 1 },
 { id: 344, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 2 },
 { id: 335, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 3 },
 { id: 334, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-29', dateID: 4 }
]
```

What I am trying to do is create an array of objects, so that everyTime [i].Date changes dateId starts back at 0 and increments like the following:

```
[
 { id: 332, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 0 },
 { id: 342, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 1 },
 { id: 344, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 0 },
 { id: 335, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 1 },
 { id: 335, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 2 },
 { id: 334, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-29', dateID: 0 }
]
```

I have tried reducing the array of objects so I had an object with the date and how many times it occurs and using a nested for loop but that didn't seem to work and I cant get it with array.map.

Comment: is it the case that everytime the date is in order. for example can there be example where Date field is not in order

Comment: The date will always be in order. I am sorting them before adding the dateID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach. Essentially what I'm doing grabbing the previously iterated item. Then I check whether the `Date` of the current item does not equal the `Date` of the previous one. If that is the case the new `dateID` is set to `0`. If the `Date` is still the same the `dateID` will be increased.

```js
const data = [
  { id: 332, tech: "bob", Date: "2022-07-25", dateID: 0 },
  { id: 342, tech: "bob", Date: "2022-07-25", dateID: 1 },
  { id: 344, tech: "bob", Date: "2022-07-26", dateID: 2 },
  { id: 335, tech: "bob", Date: "2022-07-26", dateID: 3 },
  { id: 334, tech: "bob", Date: "2022-07-29", dateID: 4 },
];

const output = data.reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  const prev = acc[i - 1];
  return [
    ...acc,
    {
      ...curr,
      dateID: prev?.Date !== curr.Date ? 0 : prev?.dateID + 1,
    },
  ];
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let data = [
 { id: 332, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 0 },
 { id: 342, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 1 },
 { id: 344, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 2 },
 { id: 335, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 3 },
 { id: 334, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-29', dateID: 4 }
]

data.forEach((el, i) => {
  el.dateID = 0
  if (el.Date == data[i - 1]?.Date) {
    el.dateID += data[i - 1].dateID + 1;
  }
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Wow Thanks for the help! Both Answers worked like a Charm. I just saw @Behemoth answer first and tested it for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
 { id: 332, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 0 },
 { id: 342, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-25', dateID: 1 },
 { id: 344, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 2 },
 { id: 335, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-26', dateID: 3 },
 { id: 334, tech: 'bob', Date: '2022-07-29', dateID: 4 }
]

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  // try to find if there is an item with a current Item dateID exist.
  const oldItemIndex = acc.findIndex(i => i.Date === item.Date);
  
  // if exist update the dateID with one
  if (oldItemIndex !== -1) {
    item.dateID = acc[oldItemIndex].dateID + 1
    acc.push(item)
    return acc
  }
  // if not update dateID to zero.
  item.dateID = 0
  acc.push(item)
  return acc

}, [])

console.log(result)
```